# Using Replace when string contains quotes

Tags: xml, powershell, replace, quotes

I read other posts and attempted their solutions, but I can't seem to get it to work for me.

I need to update multiple XML files and change a node value from `<Option name="fldsep" value="|" />`  to `<Option name="fldsep" value="~" />`.

It works when I do `{ $_.Replace("|", "~") } | Set-Content $_.FullName` and updates the XML files perfectly, but I don't want it to overwrite other `|` that are present.

I tried doing:

`{ $_.Replace('<Option name="fldsep" value="|" /> ','<Option name="fldsep" value="~" /> ') } | Set-Content $_.FullName`

but it won't update the XML file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the full code for reference:

```
$pathTest = "C:\Test" Get-ChildItem -path $pathTest -recurse -include "*.tf.*" | % {

    $con = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $con | % { $_.Replace('<Option name="fldsep" value="|" /> ','<Option name="fldsep" value="~" /> ') } | Set-Content $_.FullName

}
```

The XML section in full looks like this:

```
<TransformationSourceOptions>
  <Option name="codepage" value="ANSI" /> 
  <Option name="recsep" value="LF" /> 
  <Option name="fieldcount" value="0" /> 
  <Option name="fldsep" value="|" /> 
  <Option name="fldsdelim" value="None" /> 
  <Option name="fldedelim" value="None" /> 
  <Option name="header" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="altfldsep" value="None" /> 
  <Option name="soffset" value="0" /> 
  <Option name="autostyle" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="stylesamplesize" value="5000" /> 
  <Option name="lstrip" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="tstrip" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="field1isrectypeid" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="nullind" value="none" /> 
  <Option name="emptyfieldsnull" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="numericformatnormalization" value="False" /> 
  <Option name="layoutmismatch" value="0" /> 
</TransformationSourceOptions>
```

Comment: Are you changing one single node value in each file, or a selected number, or all there is ?

Comment: I will be changing only that one node value in every file in the folder. I will also need to change  `<Option name="header" value="False" />` from `False` to `True`, but I was going to do that portion after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of an attribute in an XML document, utilize the built-in support for XML!

```
# Load xml doc
$TransformDoc = [xml](Get-Content .\options.xml)

# Find option node and change value of "value" attribute
$TransformDoc.SelectSingleNode('//Option[@name="fldsep"]').value = "~"

# Save your changes to the document
$TransformDoc.Save("options.xml")
```

Comment: @chrisdoubleu13 Once you've got the xml document as a powershell object, you can do it for `//Options[@name="Header"]` in the same run also, no need to edit the file twice :)